# Exporting a webpage as an iPad app - not dependent on Safari?

Tags: ipad, security, web-applications, safari

My senior project is a web-based storytelling app to be viewed on iPad. The elements need to be touched with.

I was wondering if there was some sort of packaging service that will convert my pages into an independent app - I want to escape some of the features of Safari. Such as the address bar, tab bar, etc. I do not want people to be able to leave my project in the gallery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this to your header:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

you can then add to homepage and it'll remove the browser elements...but you will have to make the various page calls with ajax, or setting `window.location`...you can't just have traditional links (it'll reopen safari)

**----------------------------edit:-------------------------------**

Here's what I mean about `window.location`.

used to be `<a href="http://url">linktext</a>`

now

```
<span style="text-decorate:underline;color:#00F;" onclick="viewPage('http://url');">linktext</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewPage(p){
    window.location=p;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aw, I have one link that goes to the 2nd part of my project (same server) and it opens in safari. But this is useful if I ever have 1 isolated page. Thanks for your help. I hope I can find another solution

Comment: Can you make the link (onclick) fire a js function to change window.location? That'll keep you in the app

Comment: ah, sorry, I had a typo, it's not `window.location(p)`, it's `window.location=p` also, I work within two miles of your school

Comment: also, read this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html, you'll be able to add an icon, and a splash screen to make it appear more 'native.' email me if you have other questions, long comment exchanges don't help others as much

Comment: ROBOT WOODS. YOU HAVE SAVED MY LIFE. This is excellent. Oh so excellent. This solves so many of my problems, it is totally gallery-ready now. Before I was going to have to cover the address bar with tape, etc etc. Now theres extra space on the bottom too, I can make my pages bigger. Also, small world eh? I'm graduating soon, can you get me a job? ;)